# PhoneGap / Cordova Camera onResume returns empty object

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap, onresume

So I have an Cordova app for Android that uses official Cordova Camera plugin. App uses onResume event in order to restore app status after Android kills background Cordova task when taking photos.

I am following best practices from Cordova documentation and still have no luck in getting it done properly. When user takes photo, Android kills Cordova task in background and, according to documentation,  camera plugin should return pendingResult object with camera plugin state. But nothing like this happens at all. I have written simple debugging code:

events are addedd to app like this:

```
    function onDeviceReady() {
        document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
        document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
```

... some more code ....

```
   function onResume(event) {
        console.log("on resume event fired !!!");
        var storedState = window.localStorage.getItem(APP_STORAGE_KEY);
        if(storedState) {
            appState = JSON.parse(storedState);
            str = JSON.stringify(appState, null, 4);
            console.log("found previously stored state: "+str);
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));
        console.log(event.pendingResult);
}
```

Console output is:

`on resume event fired !!!
found previously stored state:
{
    "takingPicture": true,
    "imageURI": ""
}
{
    "isTrusted": false,
    "action": "resume"
}
undefined`

So clearly onResume event is called when Cordova app is being restarted, but event.pendingResult is not being returned from official Cordova camera plugin. Any ideas how to fix it ?

I am using Cordova 7.1.0 and cordova-plugin-camera version 2.4.1, tested on LG L90 running Android  5.0.2 and LG G3 running Android 6.0.

Ps. Also tried moving event listeners one level up like this:

```
function bodyLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
    document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
}
```

and still no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found solution. The issue is cordova-plugin-facebook4 (here version 1.9.1). As it appears, the facebook plugin messes with Cordova resume callbacks. (more details can be found here: https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/1315).

To fix it, one should navigate to

> \platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\CordovaInterfaceImpl.java

and on line 134 there is an `if(callback == null && initCallbackService != null)` which should be changed to `if( initCallbackService != null)`. That's it, unfortunately 3 days of debugging are gone.

Comment: I love you, this answer is gold! Thx you so much @peterPP1